# With an existing partitioned drive, windows 7 on one and Ubuntu on the other, how can now get rid of windows?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

Some time ago I installed Ubuntu on my Windows 7 system, going the partition drive route.  I'm now out of space on the Ubuntu partition and can't do any updates.  I want to get rid of Windows and the partition, leaving just Ubuntu on my computer.  Is there a way to do this without losing everything I have in Ubuntu?

Comment: Can you show your partition structure?  And do you have LVM partitions or Standard partitions under Ubuntu?  If you have standard partitions then even after removing Windows you will get a separate partition with free space.  That might not solve your issue of "out of space" in Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Two step process:

First Step:  With Ubuntu up and running, use `gparted` to delete the partition that has windows 7 on it.  Modify grub to remove the Windows 7 boot entry...

Second step:

Decide if you want to incorporate the space into your existing Ubuntu partition, or mount the partition as a directory within your file structure.

To incorporate, you will need to create a live USB to boot from - the one that you download from Canonical for installing Ubuntu would be great.  Boot from this USB using the 'try Ubuntu' choice.  The USB will have a copy of `gparted` on it, and you can use this to increase the size of your Ubuntu partition, although you will need to move any partitions between the unused space and your Ubuntu partition.

Should you decide to have the space mounted on the directory somewhere, you should use `gparted` to create an acceptable partition and format, and then study the `man mount` commands to learn about getting the partition online, and placing appropriate entries into `/etc/fstab`

Comment: If I simply copy the installer from Canonical, can I simply boot off the dvd and remove the partition and windows and have one big Ubuntu drive?  And if so, will it recognize my current version of Ubuntu?

Comment: You can - I suggested removing the windows partition while Ubuntu is running, so that the Ubuntu partition itself is not accidently removed.  You could perform all of this from either the CD or USB in a single session, rather then the two sessions I suggested.